# Does program fail because class lack copy ctor or proper assignment operator?

Tags: c++

I'm struggling to understand the exact reason the program fails.
Regarding the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

template < class T, size_t SIZE>
class Stack {
    T arr[SIZE] = {};
    int pos = 0;
public:
    Stack & push(const T & t) {
        arr[pos++] = t;
        return *this;
        
    }
    Stack & push(T && t) {
        arr[pos++] = std::move(t);
        return *this;
        
    }
    T pop() {
        return std::move(arr[--pos]);
        
    }
    
};

class Foo {
    std::string s;
public:
    Foo(const char* s = "@") : s(s) {}
    Foo(Foo && foo) : s(std::move(foo.s)) {}
    Foo & operator=(Foo && foo) {
        s = std::move(foo.s);
        return *this;
        
    }
    void print() const { std::cout << s << std::endl; }
    
};

int main() {
    Stack<std::string, 5> s1;
    s1.push("hi").push(std::string{ "bye" });
    std::cout << s1.pop() << std::endl;
    
        
    Stack<Foo, 5> s3;
    Foo f2;
    s3.push(f2);
        
}
```

The program fails at `s3.push(f2);` is it because Foo doesn't have a copy ctor or is it because its assignment operator function only handles Foo&& types?
I'm suspecting it's the assignment operator function but I'm not sure it's not because of copy ctor as well.

Comment: What do you mean by “program fails”? What’s the error message?

Comment: Does it fail during compile time or when running? Do you get an error message, and if so, what does it say?

Comment: Why do you suspect the failure is related to copy construction or assignment? The way you phrased your question locks us into those two options, so if the culprit is something else, the answer would be "no, none of the above", which is not all that useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you provided a custom move cosntructor and assignment operator, the compiler no longer generates default copy constructor and assignment operator.

You either need to write those too, or, even better, remove the custom move operations.

The compiler will then generate all 4 for you, and they might be better than your manually written ones (e.g. one problem is that you forgot `noexcept` on move operations, so standard containers will prefer making copies to moves in some scenarios).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the compiler tells you:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&)’
```

So you can solve it by adding that function:

```
Foo& operator=(const Foo& foo) {
    s = foo.s;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions (I will not point out design issues assuming you are just experimenting).

1. As a internal data use `vector<T>` instead of the array of fixed size and in the push that accepts the `const&` move and use `emplace_back` (nasty and amoral, also it will leave the src in invalid state).
2. Provide copy constructor to `Foo` (this is much more easier)

Comment: What does using a vector change? And why move a const reference, if it normally doesn't do anything?

Comment: you can reserve in vector size in constructor and use emplace_back with rvalue, thus no copy contractor required, only move constructor which Foo does have

Comment: Got it. But moving a const reference won't allow a move unless you also `const_cast` it (which is where it gets "amoral" :P). Instead you can keep the current `push` implementation, and call it using `s3.push(std::move(f2));`.

Comment: Yes agree, but that way you are forcing all you clients to use push with move.

Comment: Which is exactly what e.g. `std::vector` vector does if you give it a move-only type.